# issue with RazorEngine variable parsing

Tags: c#, .net, razorengine

In my page, I'd like to display a string like this:

> Today is (x)th of july

Where (x) is calculated by progam at runtime and passed as @Model.Number to RazorEngine

However the following template format will not work as I expected

> Today is @Model.Numberth of july

In many cases I have to put variables and plain text together without spaces. How can I improve my code to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using this

```
Today is @(Model.Number)th of july
```